# Get data from debian via external hard drive, command line and root user

Tags: debian, data-recovery

[Re-post from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420389/data-from-debian-to-win10-via-external-hard-drive-command-line-and-root-user)
My PC on Debian (Jessie) doesn't work well any more and I only have the command line interface (and only can connect with root). I would like to copy my data on my external hard drive (I know I should have done backups before but I made a slip up when doing it) but I don't manage to do it.
First, my PC seems not to detect it (or a usb key - NTFS), then I did these commands for now:

```
# cd /
# find . -name "exthd"
./dev/disk/by-label/exthd
./media/username/exthd
# cp -R dataFile /media/username/exthd
# chown -R username /media/username/exthd
```

But when I do an `ls -l` on `/media/username/exthd` there is only the files I copied while there are 3 other files, and when my exthd isn't connected I still find it in `/media/username` with the data I copied in (that's why I think actually my exthd isn't detected). And when I connect exthd on my other PC (on win10) there aren't my copied data (that's why I tested to make a `chown`).
NB: I already used exthd on this PC.

[Results of commands]
To resume.
`fdisk -l`:
 - `/dev/sda1` => `EFI System`
 - `/dev/sda2` => `Linux filesystem`
 - `/dev/sda3` => `Linux swap`
 - `/dev/sdb1` => `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`.
I'm using a usb key right now because I don't have exthd near me, I found its name only in `./dev/disk/by-label/myusbname` (`find` command), and it seems to be `sdb1`, same capacity in `fdisk -l` and same name in `blkid`.

Comment: There is difference between detected and mounted. Please show us output of following commands: `fdisk -l` and `blkid`

Comment: Can you just mount your drive with `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/username/exthd/` then content of the external drive will be displayed, but previous folder content will be hidden until to umount to drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made following commands (without the results):

```
# cd /
# fdisk -l
# blkid
# mount /dev/sdb1 /media/username/exthd
# cp -R /home/username/Documents /media/username/exthd
# umount /media/username/exthd
```

`/dev/sdb1`: my external hard disk as found thanks to `fdisk` and `blkid` commands.
`/media/username/exthd`: where I want to mount my disk.
`/home/username/Documents`: the folder of data I want to copy.

It worked, I recovered my data.